# FindResource throws exception on one of two identical code paths

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is for a chat application.

I am using a ValueConverer on a Gender Enum which will look at a user's settings to determine which resource to show for the given gender. Currently the app has 3 icon packs in it, which the user can choose from at any time and any new message comes in the new icon will be shown. This is defined in the IconChoice setting, which is an integer.

I am however having a problem with the female resource and I cannot figure out what the problem is. The icon will load in just fine for pack 3, but it throws a `ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException` when it is called for pack 1. Switching back and forth between packs makes no difference, it will remain to show pack 3 fine and continues to throw the exception on pack 1.

The converter:

```
public class GenderToGeometryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch (Settings.Default.IconChoice)
        {
            case 0:
            default:
                return GetGenderDataPackOne((Gender)value);
            case 1:
                return GetGenderDataPackTwo((Gender)value);
            case 2:
                return GetGenderDataPackThree((Gender)value);
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    private Geometry GetGenderDataPackOne(Gender gender)
    {
        switch (gender)
        {
            case Gender.Male:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("Male") as Geometry;
            case Gender.Female:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("Female") as Geometry;
            case Gender.None: default:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("None") as Geometry;
        }
    }

    private Geometry GetGenderDataPackTwo(Gender gender)
    {
        switch (gender)
        {
            case Gender.Male:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("Male_Square") as Geometry;
            case Gender.Female:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("Female_Square") as Geometry;
            case Gender.None: default:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("None_Square") as Geometry;
        }
    }

    private Geometry GetGenderDataPackThree(Gender gender)
    {
        switch (gender)
        {
            case Gender.Male:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("Male") as Geometry;
            case Gender.Female:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("Female") as Geometry;
            case Gender.None: default:
                return Application.Current.FindResource("None") as Geometry;
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<Path Margin="2 0" Grid.Column="1"
 Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource GFC}}"
 Data="{Binding User.Gender, Converter={StaticResource GtG}}"
 Stroke="{Binding User.Gender, Converter={StaticResource GtGS}}"
 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

And the resources itself:

```
<GeometryGroup x:Key="None">
    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" Center="10,10" />
    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Rect="0,0,0,22">
        <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="45" CenterX="10" CenterY="10" />
                <TranslateTransform X="7.5" Y="6" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
    </RectangleGeometry>
    <GeometryGroup.Transform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".4" ScaleY=".4" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </GeometryGroup.Transform>
</GeometryGroup>
<GeometryGroup x:Key="Female">
    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" Center="10,10" />
    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="2" RadiusY="10" Rect="10,19,0,12" />
    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="2" RadiusY="10" Rect="5,26,10,0" />
    <GeometryGroup.Transform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".4" ScaleY=".4" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </GeometryGroup.Transform>
</GeometryGroup>
<GeometryGroup x:Key="Male">
    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" Center="10,10" />
    <GeometryGroup>
        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="2" RadiusY="10" Rect="10,19,0,12" />
        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="2" RadiusY="10" Rect="10,30,0,10">
            <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="10.2" CenterY="30.5" Angle="-145" />
            </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
        </RectangleGeometry>
        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="2" RadiusY="10" Rect="10,30,0,10">
            <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="9.8" CenterY="30.5" Angle="145" />
            </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
        </RectangleGeometry>
        <GeometryGroup.Transform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-155" CenterX="10" CenterY="10" />
        </GeometryGroup.Transform>
    </GeometryGroup>
    <GeometryGroup.Transform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform Y="15" />
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".4" ScaleY=".4" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </GeometryGroup.Transform>
</GeometryGroup>
```

Comment: Did you debug `IconChoice` and the value? I guess that one or more parameter is not correct.

Comment: Yes, it changes just fine. Stepped through the code and it runs all the way to the end where it throws the exception, or in the case of choosing pack 3 it will run through that piece of code and load the resource fine

Comment: So the resource gets loaded correctly for pack 1 and 3? (sorry if I misunderstood)

Comment: No, it gets loaded correctly for pack 3 but not for pack 1

Comment: Is value casting to Gender ok in method Convert? usually you would need something like var gender = Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), value);

Comment: Yes, it is ok. The value send is already of type Gender as that is what I am converting from